# Open new file and quit without saving

Tags: vba, excel

I have this subroutine, I would like to quit without save from AAAAMMGG_A.xls

Thanks

```
Sub A_STEP3()
On Error GoTo Err_A_STEP3

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range
    Dim righedacopiare As Integer

   'open the file AAAAMMGG_A.xls di Flutitoli e copio le informazioni


    Workbooks.Open (MyPath2 & nomefile2(8))
    Range("A2:W2").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Windows("modello.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("A").Select
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    righedacopiare = 1000

  ' formatto le stringhe in numero
    Set rng = Worksheets("A").Range("U3:V" & righedacopiare)

    For Each c In rng
        c.Value = c.Value * 1
        c.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    Next

    Set rng2 = Worksheets("A").Range("C3:F" & righedacopiare)

    For Each d In rng2
        d.Value = "'" & d.Value
    Next

Exit_A_STEP3:
    Exit Sub

Err_A_STEP3:
    MsgBox "A_STEP3 -> " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    ERROREBLOCCO = True
    Resume Exit_A_STEP3

End Sub
```

Comment: I removed your SHOUTY CAPS... it comes across as rude

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you are capturing the new workbook in a variable so that you can specify which workbook you want to close:

```
Dim wb_A As Workbook
Set wb_A = Workbooks.Open MyPath2 & nomefile2(8)
'Do stuff here
wb_A.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Second, if you don't *want* to save, you can open the workbook in Read-Only mode:

```
Dim wb_A As Workbook
Set wb_A = Workbooks.Open MyPath2 & nomefile2(8), ReadOnly:=True
'Do stuff here
wb_A.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Using `ActiveWorkbook` is messy - always try to use full object paths (i.e. `Worksheet_Name.Range(..)` instead of just `Range(..)` or `ActiveSheet.Range(..)` where possible to avoid unexpected activity